# creating Spark dataframe from sequence of Maps

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a Sequence of maps. Each map contains column names as keys and column values as values. So one map describes one row. I do not know how many entries will be there in a map. So I can't create a fixed length tuple in my code. I want to convert the sequence to dataframe. I tried the below code:

```
val mapRDD= sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Map("col1" -> "10", "col2" -> "Rohan", "col3" -> "201"),
  Map("col1" -> "13", "col2" -> "Ross", "col3" -> "201")
  ))

val columns=mapRDD.take(1).flatMap(a=>a.keys)

val resultantDF=mapRDD.map{value=> // Exception is thrown from this block
  value.values.toList 
}.toDF(columns:_*)

resultantDF.show()
```

But it gave the below exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:414)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.rddToDataFrameHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:155)
...
```

I tried few other approaches, but nothing worked.

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using

Comment: @merenptah Spark 2.10:1.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below approach.

1. Extract `column` names and create below `dataframe` from given `rdd`

   ```
   val columns=mapRDD.take(1).flatMap(a=>a.keys).toSeq
   val df=mapRDD.map(_.values.toList).toDF

   //df look like below
   +----------------+
   |           value|
   +----------------+
   |[10, Rohan, 201]|
   | [13, Ross, 201]|
   +----------------+
   ```
2. Now create your `schema` dynamically and user defined function like below

   ```
   //Required imports
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
   import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

   //Creating udf the will return a Row of your schema
   def getRow(arr:WrappedArray[String]):Row=Row.fromSeq(arr.toSeq)

   //Creating schema
   val udfSchema=StructType(columns.map(x=>StructField(x,StringType,true)))

   //Registering udf along with schema
   val getRowUDF=udf(getRow _,udfSchema)

   //Now calling udf and generating one new column
   val df2=df.withColumn("temp",getRowUDF(df.col("value")))

   //df2 will look like
   +----------------+--------------+
   |           value|          temp|
   +----------------+--------------+
   |[10, Rohan, 201]|[10,Rohan,201]|
   | [13, Ross, 201]| [13,Ross,201]|
   +----------------+--------------+
   ```
3. Now get your final `dataframe` from df2 using your `column` `list`

   ```
   val query=columns.map(x=>df2.col("temp."+x))
   df2.select(query:_*).show

   //output
   +----+-----+----+
   |col1| col2|col3|
   +----+-----+----+
   |  10|Rohan| 201|
   |  13| Ross| 201|
   +----+-----+----+
   ```

Comment: This solution assumes that there are exactly 3 entries in each map. I can't assume that. I do not know, at compile time, how many entries will be present in each map.

Comment: @madhusudhan Please find the updated answer. It is long but your desired.